# Extract css class from drag-and-drop event in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events, drag-and-drop

I have several draggable image elements with certaing css class and one canvas element on my html page. Also canvas element catches `dragStart`, `dragOver` and `drop` events. How is it possible to find out image css class in `drop` event? Image src I can get with following code: `e.dataTransfer.getData('text')`.

**UPDATE:**

Here my javascript function (generated from C# with ScriptSharp):

```
_drop: function Collage$_drop(e) {
    /// <param name="e" type="ElementEvent">
    /// </param>
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = _privateUtils.getMouseX(e) - 20;
    var y = _privateUtils.getMouseY(e) - 20;
    this._loadCollageImage(x, y, e.dataTransfer.getData('text'));
}
```

Is it possible to get css image class or another unique element feature (attribute, id) from `e` or by the other way?

Comment: Can you post some more code? Are you dropping images from another document or from the desktop?

Comment: @David, I posted code. I am dropping image element to canvas element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want information to be available in the `drop` event, add it to the `dataTransfer` object in the `drag` event.  Or just set the text to be the ID of the element, and fetch the required information from the DOM.